# Как убрать (или изменить цвет) этой полосы в webStorm?

Tags: webstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

недавно начала использовать вебшторм. поставила материал тему. вс

Answer (score 0):

Это change marks, позволяют визуально отмечать locally modified, etc. строки и по клику в левом поле видеть diff. Убрать полосу можно, оключив **Highlight modified lines in gutter** в **Settings | Editor | General**.
Цвет можно поменять в **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | VCS**, **Editor Gutter > Modified lines**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]